# UINavigationItem's title disappears when view controller is pushed

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem, iphone-5, ios8.4

I am having an issue with my view controller's navigation item's title. Indeed, I am setting it in the `viewDidLoad` method like this :

```
self.navigationItem.title = "Title"
```

The problem is that when I push this view controller from another on to the navigation stack, I see the title while the transition but as soon as the transition ends, it disappears... I checked in the debugger, the title is still set... I tried with the titleView property either with no success...
By the way, the problem only show up on iPhone 5 with iOs < 9...

Comment: If you've got a UINavigationController, how about `[self.navigationController setTitle:@"Title"];`?

Comment: Still the same. :/ The title is shown while transition is active and then disappears.

Comment: Or you could try managing the NavigationBar yourself:
`GSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, result.size.width, 40)];
_navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
[_navBar setItems:@[_navItem]];
[self.view addSubview:_navBar];`

Answer (score 0):

Let's try that as an answer:

`CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, result.size.width, 40)];
_navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
[_navBar   setItems:@[_navItem]];
[self.view addSubview:_navBar];`

Comment: This work for the title. He stays this way but I have no back button even setting it manually. Do you know how to link this navigation bar to navigation controller ?

Comment: According to this discussion on the Apple developer boards (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2508892?threadID=2508892), you can either create your own Back button or set the Back button attribute in the storyboard for the previous viewController. Also, it appears to matter whether you put the code in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear -- whichever one works.

Comment: Well I set it like this but it has no effet (it did when it was on the original tabbar) : self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)